# How do I keep my properties inline with attributes as well?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, attributes

I would like to find a way to tell visual studio to keep my properties in my classes inline with the attributes. An example.

```
[DataMember] int ID { get; set; }
[DataMember] public int DivisionID { get; set; }
[DataMember] public string Name { get; set; }
[DataMember] public int MyID { get; set; }
[DataMember] public string ContactName { get; set; }
```

But if I were to modify the class manually and hit save it auto adjusts the file to look like this.

```
[DataMember] 
int ID { get; set; }
[DataMember] 
public int DivisionID { get; set; }
[DataMember] 
public string Name { get; set; }
[DataMember] 
public int MyID { get; set; }
[DataMember] 
public string ContactName { get; set; }
```

**Edit**

Just so everyone knows. This isn't a best practice question. I am just trying to learn if the editor has this capability. These code files are being auto generated by a code generator we had just finished. It is more of an annoyance that keeps happening and we would like to stop it from doing so. I know there are several options for modifying the editor but didn't know if anyone knew of a good workaround to this problem or if it existed.

I really appreciate anyone's insight into our question.

Comment: What happens when you have multiple attributes? `[DataMember][Required][XmlIgnore][Deprecated] int ID {get;set;}` Is that what you want? To me that's incredibly confusing.

Comment: Well with multiple it would be [DataParameter, DataMember]

Comment: @DaveZych `[DataMember,Required,XmlIgnore,Deprecated] int ID { get; set; }` would be better, but yeah I still prefer having each attribute on a separate line.

Comment: The thinking behind this. The code files are being created with a new generator and the attributes are always going to be the same on each property so we aren't too concerned about them being on different lines or anything like that

Comment: It's not the editor that is causing the formatting its the code generator. If you are using `T4` files you could edit the file but if it is a compiled generator there is not much you could do.

Comment: We wrote the generator, it formats how we want at the top of the post here. However, upon making an edit to one of the files they auto correct to the second code block we see there.

Comment: Maybe you can find something in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting? You can disable auto-formatting there, but it will apply to **all** your code files, not only the generated ones. Probably, you may even find a setting in the subsections (e.g. "New Lines"?!) which accepts attributes on the same line as properties.

Comment: I think the best option would be to either (a) fix your generator to generate stuff that is in line with VS’ code formatter, or to (b) have a policy that basically says that you should never ever manually touch automatically generated files.

Comment: +1 I have fields like this: [SerializeField] GameObject _name on a single line, and Visual Studio keeps seperating them. When I have like 10 fields with that attribute it's taking so much more space! I find the top code in your example much more readable.

Comment: @Soeholm Agreed! We thought the same about readability

Comment: @meanbunny: I would strongly advise the use of partial classes, so that no-one needs to edit the generated code.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks we implemented that especially for our constructors and any extra class methods we wanted to keep. Completely off topic but the code generator is working so smooth. About to finish our Add-In for ease of use.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, the answer is that "Visual Studio" doesn't have that option. It isn't the ideal answer, but sometimes the answer is that it can't be done without new code.

If you go here . . .

Tools | Options | Text Editor | C# | Formatting

. . . then yes, you can turn off autoformating completely, which to me is not a solution.

However, if you go to . . .

Tools | Options | Text Editor | C# | Formatting | New Lines

. . . there is not option or setting here for new lines after an Attributes. This option or setting needs to exist.

So this feature would have to be added to Visual Studio. I don't know if it can be added by anybody but Microsoft, so the only solution is to submit and enhancement request.

Comment: Autoformatting is driven by configuration files.  I'm not convinced that the only solution is to ask the almighty Microsoft.

Comment: I thought I could find a config file, too. I searched pretty hard. I even pulled out ProcMon to see if a config file was touched when I changed settings. I would be more than happy to be proven wrong!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve this in the following way:

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting

Uncheck all the relevant ones (e.g. format completed block on })

Obviously this will affect all the automatic block formatting when you write code.

Another solution is moving to VS2012, which in my opinion doesn't do this (still does it on pasting but this is less prominent).

Comment: It might be worth noting that Visual Studio won't automatically reformat your code unless you ask it to, so manual formatting is still possible.